# How to apply for an Irish visa if we don't have a copy of previous visa refusal letter?

Tags: ireland

I am planning on applying for a visitor visa to Ireland for my mom. We had applied for a visitor visa for my mom to Canada in 2014. It got refused due to insufficient documents.

We lost that letter. How do we apply for a visitor visa without a previous refusal letter. What is the possibility of rejection in case of no refusal letter submitted.

Comment: Canada will know about that refusal and have a copy of that refusal letter. So all you would have to say truthfully is that you had a refusal letter and lost it.

Answer (score 1):

Canada will have an electronic record of the application. If you applied online, you may still be able to [sign in to your account](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/account.html?_ga=2.3113840.1386606308.1529171749-1420682779.1528551134):

> Under **View my submitted applications or profiles** click on **check status and messages.**
>
> If you applied online for an **eTA**, you can [check online](https://onlineservices-servicesenligne.cic.gc.ca/eta/applicationQuery?lang=en&_ga=2.2925808.1386606308.1529171749-1420682779.1528551134). You’ll need the application number that is on the email confirmation we sent you.
>
> **Paper applications**
>
> You can check the status of your paper application online by:
>
> - using the [online tool](https://services3.cic.gc.ca/ecas/security.do?lang=en&_ga=2.263611468.1386606308.1529171749-1420682779.1528551134), which is updated daily or
> - creating an online account and linking your paper application to it. You’ll get:
>
>   - detailed application status in real-time and
>   - messages about your application online instead of by mail.

Failing those, you might have to [contact Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/contact-ircc.html).